# I have nginx, mysql and an app in separate docker containers and they are configured fine. I am now attempting to get xdebug working but so far not

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have been having issues with trying to get xdebug to play nice with the VS code IDE when using docker container.

I have nginx, mysql and an app in separate docker containers and they are configured fine I think. I am now attempting to get xdebug working but so far not.

First I installed the module PHP debug in the VS Code IDE then I installed  the php xdebug module using the docker file. This was installed and apparently set up fine. See the image generated by phpinfo() below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I then try to get the debugger working with my IDE. I have the debugger pretty much up and running local sites i.e. not in docker.

I have tried to follow various paths to get VS Code to work with xdebug but so far no success. Firstly my yml and my docker files which seem to work fine.

The yml file and the docker files are as follows:

yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ""
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    container_name: gio-project-app
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19-alpine
    container_name: gio-project-nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8002:80
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  db:
    container_name: gio-project-db
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
      - ./storage/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3308:3306
```

And here is my docker file

```
FROM php:8.0.2-fpm

RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    zip \
    vim \
    unzip

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /var/www
```

As I have said I have been down various paths to try to get the whole thing working - the latest path I've been down can be found here https://stevegeorge.net/2022/02/10/setting-up-xdebug-3-on-a-docker-container-with-visual-studio-code/

I added the below to my `docker-compose.yml file` This was added under 'app' in the yml file

```
 extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    environment:
      XDEBUG_MODE: develop,debug
      XDEBUG_CONFIG:
        client_host=host.docker.internal
        start_with_request=yes
```

Then on my 'app' container in the directory: `/usr/local/etc/php` as suggested by the link above I added the below:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
```

So I reload all of the containers after `docker restart $(docker ps -q)`

I go back to my VS Code IDE and try to use the the xdebug_info() function - it does not work.

So I go to Run/Start debugging and select to listen on ports 9000 and 9003. I refresh the page in  the browser which is the one which I am watching in the IDE. Nothing happens.

Any help in all of this would be very much appreciated.

If any of this is not clear please get back and I will try to clarify.

Regards Clive Corner